# QOS on a Cisco DPC3939?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, qos

So with the Xfinity triple play package they issue a Cisco DPC3939 router. Now, I don't know if any of you have any experience with it or not, but suffice to say that it sucks in terms of both functionality and features. Well, recently my patience has been put to the test by my father in law who is staying here, keeping all three of his devices connected via the Wi-Fi at all times, and I'd like to limit his bandwidth, however I find no way to do this via the gateway. I don't see any QOS functionality at all. My question is; is there anything I can do to rectify this, is there any open source firmware I can install to the Cisco DPC3939 to make this happen, am I missing something, or do I just need to get a new router and put the bookend on bridge mode?

Answer (score 0):

As a Comcast customer with the same router, I can tell you that Comcast puts its own firmware on the router that severely restricts its functionality.  I also heard last week from a Comcast tech support rep that Comcast is trying to eliminate the DPC3939 from service because Comcast allegedly has had a lot of problems with them.  Not sure if that's true or not, but it is what she told me.

Another thing that may be killing your bandwidth is the fact that Comcast opts you in by default to its Xfinity public internet access and your wireless router whether you're aware of it or not is being used as a public wifi hotspot by Comcast.  Follow the instructions in the link below to disable it.  Perhaps that will help improve your performance:  http://customer.comcast.com/help-and-support/internet/disable-xfinity-wifi-home-hotspot/